# Dropdown list value from view to controller in yii

Tags: yii

I'm new to yii.I have one dropdownlist and I populate value using the database and save the selected value to database. I can populate values from db but I can't get the values from dropdown and save to database.

```
$model = new TCategoryDescription();
$model->parent_id =='0';
echo $form->labelEx($model,'MainCategoryName'); 
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'fk_i_cat_id', CHtml::listData(TCategoryDescription::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'parent_id=0')), 'fk_i_cat_id', 'cat_name'),
array('prompt'=>'Select Main Category'),array('selected'=>'true','ajax' => array('type'=>'POST','url'=>yii::app()->baseUrl.'/tcategorydescription/subtest',
```

Comment: Is this your view or what?

Comment: [CHtml::activeDropDownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail) takes 4 parameters. You have 5. Merge the last 2 parameters.